# On Android, is it necessary to remove a sensor listener when an activity is destroyed?

Tags: java, android, listener, sensors

On the Android platform, `Activity` objects may register `SensorEventListener`'s. There are examples that show the `Listener` object being explicitly removed when the `Activity` to which it belongs is destroyed. But other examples do not include this step, suggesting that this may be done automatically. That would make the extra bit of code redundant. I am not sure if that is true.

My question is: if a `SensorEventListener` is registered by an `Activity`, what resources (if any) will remain allocated to the `Listener` if it is not explicitly removed when the `Activity` is destroyed?

Comment: This is far too vague to answer - it really depends what you're using it for and what kind of listener.

Comment: @RyanMentley He specifically asks about sensor listeners.  This is completely answerable.

Comment: Which sensors?  What are they using it for?  How is the listener registered (application start, activity create/start/resume...)?  Is the information needed if the app is running in the background with no running activities?  What about when the activity is no longer visible, but not destroyed?  It should _probably_ be removed in `onStop`, not `onDestroy`, but it's honestly very difficult to tell without at least a general description.

Comment: @RyanMentley None of those questions matter.  If you leave a dangling sensor listener, its a memory leak in Android as the registration is not lifecycle aware and will not unregister it, leaving a reference to the listener and anything it references.  You need to unregister it in onDestroy at the latest.  THere's no situation where it doesn't without leaking memory.  This is true regardless of what type of sensor it is, or when in the lifecycle of the Activity its created.  There may be situations where you want to do it sooner, but you must do it by that point to avoid leaks.

Comment: Sidestepping the fact that there are absolutely situations where you would want to continue listening to sensors after onDestroy, since that's _probably_ not what they're doing..."There may be situations where you want to do it sooner" is exactly my point, and why you need more information to give a full answer, especially as I suspect the answer is "you should unregister it in `onStop` and register in `onStart`".  Anyway, I think we've both made our points, and unregistering in onDestroy is probably good enough given Android's management of background apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to remove it yourself before Activity destruction.  If you don't, you'll cause a memory leak.  Depending on your implementation, it could be a bad one.

If the entire app is killed, then the listener goes away because everything in the app goes away.  But I wouldn't rely on specific behavior causing the app to die-  just unregister it in onDestroy of whatever Activity you register it in.  The easiest way to do that is to use a LifecycleObserver